# What font is this and how to write this in Latex?

Tags: fonts, latex

I want to use the font like [image] to add some API names in my paper, but I don't know what the font it is. Could you point out the font name of this example? Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for typewriter? `\texttt{send()}`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for typewriter font, which can be enabled via `\texttt{}` or `{ \ttfamily ...}`, or more semantically for your usage via one of the verbatim environments, e.g. `\verb|send()|`

(for the exact font family, you could have a look at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html)

---

However more semantically